# JPA-Hibernate: UniqueConstraint on OneToOne & ManyToOne JoinColumns

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, unique-constraint

I need to set an unique constraint on a few JoinColumns of OneToOne and ManyToOne relationships, but Hibernate seems to not found these columns even if I set the names correctly in the @JoinColumn annotations.
This seems strange to me since the same constraint is working fine with Liquibase.

Here is my entity class:

```
package entities;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

import javax.persistence.*;

import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * A MyAnswer.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_answer",
    uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"question_id, questionnaire_id", "user_id"})
)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Document(indexName = "myanswer")
public class MyAnswer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "mycheck")
    private String mycheck;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Answer answer;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
    private Question question;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "questionnaire_id")
    private Questionnaire questionnaire;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMycheck() {
        return mycheck;
    }

    public MyAnswer mycheck(String mycheck) {
        this.mycheck = mycheck;
        return this;
    }

    public void setMycheck(String mycheck) {
        this.mycheck = mycheck;
    }

    public Answer getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

    public MyAnswer answer(Answer answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
        return this;
    }

    public void setAnswer(Answer answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    public Question getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public MyAnswer question(Question question) {
        this.question = question;
        return this;
    }

    public void setQuestion(Question question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public Questionnaire getQuestionnaire() {
        return questionnaire;
    }

    public MyAnswer questionnaire(Questionnaire questionnaire) {
        this.questionnaire = questionnaire;
        return this;
    }

    public void setQuestionnaire(Questionnaire questionnaire) {
        this.questionnaire = questionnaire;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public MyAnswer user(User user) {
        this.user = user;
        return this;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        MyAnswer myAnswer = (MyAnswer) o;
        if (myAnswer.getId() == null || getId() == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return Objects.equals(getId(), myAnswer.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(getId());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyAnswer{" +
            "id=" + getId() +
            ", mycheck='" + getMycheck() + "'" +
            "}";
    }
}
```

Below the thrown exception log:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to create unique key constraint (question_id, questionnaire_id, user_id) on table my_answer: database column 'question_id, questionnaire_id' not found. Make sure that you use the correct column name which depends on the naming strategy in use (it may not be the same as the property name in the entity, especially for relational types)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at project.App.main(App.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to create unique key constraint (question_id, questionnaire_id, user_id) on table my_answer: database column 'question_id, questionnaire_id' not found. Make sure that you use the correct column name which depends on the naming strategy in use (it may not be the same as the property name in the entity, especially for relational types)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.buildUniqueKeyFromColumnNames(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:2074)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.buildUniqueKeyFromColumnNames(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1935)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processUniqueConstraintHolders(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1923)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1595)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:360)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:382)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:371)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 19 common frames omitted

2018-05-15 17:25:20.943  WARN 16173 --- [neut-Executor-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection   : HikariPool-1 - Connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@669c1cb9 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08003), ErrorCode(0)
```

Comment: Quick question: if you delete the unique constraint declaration, the application starts fine?

Comment: yes it starts just fine

Comment: How are you creating your tables? Are you using the JPA setting that create tables from you configured annotations?

Comment: try adding a naming strategy . org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

Comment: the tables are created by Liquibase at startup, and the column names are correct. Let's try with the suggested naming strategy

Comment: Why don't you create the constraint with liquibase also??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your constraint declaration is wrong. Instead of

```
@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"question_id, questionnaire_id", "user_id"})
```

use

```
@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"question_id", "questionnaire_id", "user_id"})
```

Note the difference in the quotation marks. You need a 3 element String array for column names for 3 column constraint, but you had only a 2 element String array, with the first element being an invalid column name reference.